How does this 18th century map interpret the words "colony" and "province"?

This is a follow-up to this earlier question.
The first-ever comprehensive dictionary of English was Samuel Johnson's dictionary, published in 1755. One answer to the earlier question quoted from that dictionary:

Colony 1. A body of people drawn from the mother-country to inhabit some distant place.  2. The country planted; a plantation.

That answer did not mention this other word:

Province  1. a country governed by a delegate.

This creates an impression that the 13 colonies were called "colonies" because they were populated by persons who relocated from Britain, and were called "provinces" because their governors were appointed by the British king.
But somewhere on the internet I found this map (I don't remember where) claiming to have been published in 1776. It seems a bit odd that as late as 1776 it was being claimed that what we now call Vermont was still reported to be a part of New Hampshire. But looking more closely, I see that it says "COLONY OF CONNECTICUT" but "PROVINCE OF MASSACHUSETTS BAY" and "PROVINCE OF NEW HAMPSHIRE."
Why was one of them referred to as a "colony" while two others were called "provinces"?

A quick look at Wikipedia shows that the Province of Massachusetts Bay included multiple colonies and territories. The Connecticut Colony apparently did not belong to a larger province.

Not complaining about the question itself, but I'm gonna say what I always say when a post makes an argument relying on the authority of a dictionary: There is no authority for the English language outside of, well, us collectively. Dictionaries are descriptive, not prescriptive.

@T.E.D. : Why should something that is descriptive, not prescriptive, not be cited as an authority? A respected atlas could be cited to resolve a question about whether Scotland is north or south of England, although the atlas is descriptive. Johnson's dictionary provides authoritative descriptions of the use of the English language in mid-18th-century English. Why should it not be cited as an authority on how a word was used at that time? Besides, obviously some dictionaries are prescriptive. And if you ask whether that is as it ought to be, the answer is very far from self-evident.

@T.E.D. : And I'm not sure you've even understood my question. I was not citing this dictionary as an authority on how words OUGHT to be used, but rather as an authority on how words WERE used at that time and place.

@T.E.D. : Frankly, it looks as if you're just confusing issues by misrepresenting what the question says.

A much more legible version of this map is at https://www.loc.gov/item/74692155 , The map (and lettering) was drawn in 1755.

@kimchilover : If it was drawn in 1755, that would explain why all of what later became Vermont was treated as part of New Hampshire. It was a disputed territory (between New York and New Hampshire) but then governed as a de facto part of New Hampshire.

@kimchilover : The map you linked to says "KONEKTIKUT" whereas the one I posted here says "CONNECTICUT". So it's not the same one. Might the one I posted be from a later edition of the same book?

Google "A map of the most inhabited part of New England" for many copies of this  map, with varying 18th century dates.  There was a lot of map plagiarism and reprinting, and so on, and differences in the title cartouche, etc.

See the 1776 Augsburg redrawing by Lotter (https://www.raremaps.com/gallery/detail/68553/a-map-of-the-most-inhabited-part-of-new-england-containing-t-lotter-mead )for a closer match to your map.  It is a redrawing and reprinting of the 1755 London  map by Jeffferys that I referred to before.

Because that was how each one decided to call themselves:
Province of New_Hampshire
Province of Massachusetts Bay
Connecticut Colony
See that they match the "Before Statehood" information here:
New_Hampshire
Massachusetts
Connecticut
While Rhode Island had a weirder official name as written in the map.
maybe somebody more versed in colonial law could answer if the different names had some relevance legally, or if it was just fashion or taste.

I can see the name "RHODE ISLAND AND PROVIDENCE PLANTATIONS" on the map, and I know that was the official name of the state until less than four years ago in 2020. But does it have some other word in the place where "province" or "colony" is found?
